# Use of word "Doubt" when asking question

Tags: discussion

**Edit:** Should be closed as duplicate of - [Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429).  Though that is on another SE site...

What language/culture commonly translates confusion, misunderstanding, or question into the word "doubt"?  I see this quite often on SO.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=doubt

Comment: This question may not actually be useful to anyone, including myself :) If there is a better place to ask this, or it is better left unasked, please let me know rather than down-voting.

Comment: I don't know, maybe this is on-topic at [english.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Indeed.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/a-question-regarding-the-use-of-doubt-to-mean-question)

Comment: @Blorgbeard: That's a negative, ghost rider.  The pattern is full.  Indeed what? :)

Comment: @Tobias: Oh, and it's already a dupe on that site.  Thanks for the info :)  Vote to close?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/a-question-regarding-the-use-of-doubt-to-mean-question

Comment: Indeed it is on-topic at english.SE ("Indeed" was a link to  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/a-question-regarding-the-use-of-doubt-to-mean-question )

Comment: @Blorg: Oh, missed that it was a link.  Thank you as well

Comment: @Merlyn I guess so. Too bad we can't close cross-site dupes... But you can manually edit in a `closed as duplicate of...` link of course

Comment: I think someone asked about the word "lakh" on meta.